# Как собрать и выполнить программу в C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Я установил С++Builder 6 и ввел в него элементарную програму на С++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    printf("Hello, World!");
    getch();
}
```

Она откомпилировалась, но исполняемый exe-файл автоматически не запускается (под исполняемым файлом я имею ввиду черное dos-окошко). Как можно устранить эту проблему, посоветуйте, может что-то нужно в настройках поменять, ведь не удобно запускать каждый раз откомпилированую програму вручную. Заранее спасибо, всем кто отзовется ответить на мой вопрос.

Comment: Небольшой совет на будущее, если решите делать приложения с GUI, изучите что и где необходимо выставить в настройках, чтобы собранный проект запускался на всех компьютерах. Насколько я помню, там необходимо включение дополнительных библиотек в приложение.

Comment: >Я установил С++Builder 6 и ввел в него элементарную програму на С++:

И написал код на C...

Comment: как найти компонент (TCompanent*Owner)

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажмите не Make/Build, а Run (Зелёная стрелочка).

Comment: Оказалось, это я затупил. Чтобы в С++Builder 6  программа без специально созданной формы (визуальной оболочки), то есть просто с  досовской консольной оболочкой, компилировалась и запускалась, нужно сделать так: запустить команду run (ЗЕЛЕНАЯ СТРЕЛОЧКА). Если програма написана правильно, то запустится досовское окно с текстом, который я и хотел запрограммировать (Hello word). 

